# Iterating indices with negative step in Rust's "ndarray"?

Tags: rust, rust-ndarray

I want to iterate the *indices* for an array slice according to an arbitrary `SliceInfo`, possibly in "reverse" order.

Given an `ndarray` (let's say 2D, for simplicity) I want to be able to specify a `SliceInfo` such as `s![5..10, 10..20;-1]` and have an iteration of `IndicesIter<Ix2>` giving me:

```
(5,19), (5,18), ... (5,10), (6,19) ... (6,10) ...
```

where the outer dimension runs forwards, and the inner dimension runs in reverse.

I can specify this in the `s!` macro and the generated `SliceInfo` instance contains the negative step, but there seem no way at all to coerce the library to iterate the indices in that order.

If I apply the slice to an array:

```
arr.slice(s![5..10, 10..20;-1])
```

Then I get the slice, with elements running "in reverse" according to the slice, but their indices are of course running "forwards" from 0. This is expected, and what I want is another API for just iterating the indices as they would appear in the original (un-sliced) array, but there appears to just be no API for this. I hope I'm wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this API exists. The most obvious solution is to construct the array of indices (`Array2::from_shape_fn(arr.raw_dim(), |ix| ix)`), then slice and iterate that. This requires a whole allocation, but is conceptually simple.

Comment: Yeah, that's not ideal. I ended up just writing one separately, but if I'm missing an API in `ndarray`, I'd love to know.